# Why are several of my locale components Spanish?

Tags: macintosh, locale, xubuntu

Even though I've repeatedly configured the locale on my Xubuntu 20.20 system on a MacBook Pro to be "en_US.UTF-8", the "locale" command insists that on several formats be "es_MX.UTF-8". Here's my "locale" output:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_TIME=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=POSIX
LC_MONETARY=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_MX.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Have you seen [this link](https://www.tecmint.com/set-system-locales-in-linux/)? I don't know *why* your localization is messed up, but that *should* help you fix it.

Comment: I haven't seen that link, but tried everything it suggests to no effect. I did, however, find that removing several spanish-related packages (which should not have been necessary) and rebooting reverted to the en_US.UTF locale. Thanks in any case.

Comment: I've listed a set of files to start with [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/56044/5223). Pls see them and report back